# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' with Google Maps API

Tags: json, swift, google-maps, coordinates

In my application I use Apple maps with the help of Google Places API Autocomplete to have a complete working system, and I used Google Maps Web API to have the ability to get info about a certain places from Google by sending the latitude and longitude that has been converted from the location on the map to a real coordinate.

I used the following function to get the info:

```
func getAddressForLatLng(latitude: String, longitude: String) -> Array <String> {

    var location_info = [String]() // Array to Contain the returned info from Google

    let url = NSURL(string: "\(base_url)latlng=\(latitude),\(longitude)&key=\(api_key)") // url + latitude + longitude + api key
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) // get the content of the url
    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary // get the JSON from the url

    if let result = json["results"] as? NSArray {

        if let address = result[0]["address_components"] as? NSArray {

            for value in 0...5 {

                if let place = address[value]["short_name"]{

                    location_info.append(place as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return location_info
}
```

but when I test the application on my iPhone an I keep getting the following outside the range error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (4) beyond bounds (4)'

and I tested every possible solution for the array but I am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write the `for-in` loop like this `for value in 0...address.count-1`

I have re-write your code like this:

```
 func getAddressForLatLng(latitude: String, longitude: String) -> Array <String> {

    var location_info = [String]() // Array to Contain the returned info from Google

    let url = NSURL(string: "\(base_url)latlng=\(latitude),\(longitude)&key=\(api_key)") // url + latitude + longitude + api key
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) // get the content of the url
    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary // get the JSON from the url

    if let result = json["results"] as? NSArray {

      if let address = result[0]["address_components"] as? NSArray {

        for value in 0...address.count-1 {

          if let place = address[value]["short_name"]{

            location_info.append(place as! String)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return location_info
  }
```

Comment: Thank you man it's working perfectly now. Can you please explain what is the problem with my previous version.